# What's the word for a tube out of a body that connects to another tube?

Tags: word-request

What's the word for a tube out of a body that connects to another tube?

Let's say we connect a tube into a vein (or artery) to feed blood to a patient. A tube that connects to an artery and then connects to a different part of the same artery is called a bypass, but I am not sure what an open-ended tube or connection is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general description would be IV (intravenous) access.

From your description, it could be an indwelling catheter/line. There are varying types:

- [Hickman line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hickman_line)
- [Central venous catheter (or central line)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_venous_catheter)
- [PIC line (peripherally inserted central line)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripherally_inserted_central_catheter)

An IV [cannula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannula) would also match your description. They have a shorter tube, not longer than the needle that's used to place it under the skin.

Answer (score 3):

A [cannula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannula):

> cannula (/ˈkænjʊlə/; Latin meaning 'little reed'; plural cannulae or cannulas)[1] is a tube that can be inserted into the body, often for the delivery or removal of fluid or for the gathering of samples.